# How to rotation an svg icon wrapped in a button on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to add an css animation to svg which is wrapped inside button.

**Template**

```
<button class="rotate"> 
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="1em" height="1em" style="-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path fill="#626262" d="M12 17a1.72 1.72 0 0 1-1.33-.64l-4.21-5.1a2.1 2.1 0 0 1-.26-2.21A1.76 1.76 0 0 1 7.79 8h8.42a1.76 1.76 0 0 1 1.59 1.05a2.1 2.1 0 0 1-.26 2.21l-4.21 5.1A1.72 1.72 0 0 1 12 17z" />
  </svg>
  click!
</button>
```

**Js File**

```
$(".rotate").click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass("down")  ; 
});
```

**CSS File**

```
.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to rotate the button or the svg inside? Right now, you are targeting the entire button to be rotated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the click event target the `svg` for rotation. You also need to remove the style attribute from your `svg`

```js
document.getElementById("rotate").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".rotate").classList.add("down");
});
```

```css
.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<button id="rotate"> 
  <svg class="rotate" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" width="1em" height="1em" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path fill="#626262" d="M12 17a1.72 1.72 0 0 1-1.33-.64l-4.21-5.1a2.1 2.1 0 0 1-.26-2.21A1.76 1.76 0 0 1 7.79 8h8.42a1.76 1.76 0 0 1 1.59 1.05a2.1 2.1 0 0 1-.26 2.21l-4.21 5.1A1.72 1.72 0 0 1 12 17z" />
  </svg>
  click!
</button>
```